# How to fix press effect BottomNavigation become invisible using ripple - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview, material-components, material-components-android

I use background=ripple to make press effect in BottomNavigation, but in my case, MyBottomNavigation color is dark so it's seem became invisible due the ripple effect color is grey, is there another way to fix that?

//MainActivity.java

```
//BottomNavigation
    BottomNavigationView mBottomNav = findViewById(R.id.Bottom_Navigation);

    mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;

            switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.Nav_Home:
                    selectedFragment = new HomePageFragment();
                    break;

                /*case R.id.Nav_Favorites:
                selectedFragment = new FavoritesPageFragment();
                    break;*/

                /*case R.id.Nav_Favorites:
                    selectedFragment = new SettingPageFragment();
                    break;*/

                case R.id.Nav_Follow:
                    selectedFragment = new FollowPageFragment();
                    break;

                /*case R.id.Nav_Chat:
                    selectedFragment = new ChatPageFragment();
                    break;*/

                case R.id.Nav_Profile:
                    selectedFragment = new ProfilePageFragment();
                    break;
            }

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Fragment_Container, selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }


    });


    mBottomNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

//activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/Bottom_Navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlack"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect_raised"
    app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/navTextActive"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/navTextInactive"

    app:itemTextColor="#ff0000"/>
```

//Ripple.xml (Effect for press)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/colorWhite">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        <corners android:radius="7dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

//UPDATED

//Activity.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/Bottom_Navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"

    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/navTextActive"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/navTextInactive"
    app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
    app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"

    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    app:itemRippleColor="@color/bottomnav_ripple"
    />
```

//bottomnav_ripple.xml (I put it in res/color)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Selected. -->

<item android:alpha="0.68" android:color="#21FFFF" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.66" android:color="#21FFFF" android:state_focused="true" android:state_hovered="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.62" android:color="#21FFFF" android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.54" android:color="#21FFFF" android:state_hovered="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.50" android:color="#21FFFF" android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Unselected. -->

<item android:alpha="0.68" android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.66" android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_focused="true" android:state_hovered="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.62" android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.54" android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_hovered="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.50" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
```

//shape.xml (I put it in res/drawable)(The color still invisible if I use black color in shape.xml, so I try using purple color but it still grey)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_purple" />
<corners android:radius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

[image: it still grey]

Comment: add your xml file

Comment: post above updated

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:background` only for the shape and `app:itemRippleColor` to define the ripple on the item:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      android:background="@drawable/shape"
      app:itemRippleColor="@color/bottomnav_ripple"
      ../>
```

where `shape.xml` is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
  <corners android:radius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

and `bottomnav_ripple.xml` something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Selected. -->

<item android:alpha="0.68" android:color="#21FFFF" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.66" android:color="#21FFFF" android:state_focused="true" android:state_hovered="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.62" android:color="#21FFFF" android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.54" android:color="#21FFFF" android:state_hovered="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.50" android:color="#21FFFF" android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- Unselected. -->

<item android:alpha="0.68" android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.66" android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_focused="true" android:state_hovered="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.62" android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.54" android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_hovered="true"/>
<item android:alpha="0.50" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

</selector>
```

Change the color and the alpha channel as you prefer.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that is what I want to make, I put shape.xml and bottomnav_ripple in drawable folder, and I added //android:background="@drawable/shape"
        //app:itemRippleColor="@drawable/bottomnav_ripple", but it's not connected //AAPT: error: attribute itemRippleColor (aka com.indofun.android.indojoy:itemRippleColor) not found.

Comment: @SunggakiChannel `itemRippleColor` is a **color** not a drawable. You have to put the files in `res/color` folder

Comment: but this method app:itemRippleColor doesn't found in BottomNavigation library, AAPT: error: attribute itemRippleColor (aka com.indofun.android.indojoy:itemRippleColor) not found.

Comment: @SunggakiChannel Use the 1.1.0-beta01 version

Comment: Thanks 1.1.0-beta01 has itemRippleColor, I updated my post and include the picture of my app, it's seems still grey color